# Cannot read property 'sdeptname' of undefined in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented simple table in angular 2 using angular material...I have taken two mat-table where the selected rows from first table are transferred to second table on clicking **Move To Table 2** and vice versa on clicking **Move To Table 1**

But as I select and Click on **Move To Table 2** ,all the rows from my first table are getting spliced and I am getting the following error in my console as shown below.

[image]

please access my sample example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-mlqthx?file=app%2Faccount.component.ts)

Comment: Your example does not contain the DepartmentlockComponent. Where is it an who calls it?

Comment: thats actually account.component....

Comment: its because i named it as AccountComponent in the stackblitz and in my local the name is DepartmentlockComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use your nested objects in your `HTML` like this `element?.sdeptname`. 
This ensures even if the value is null for element for sometime it wont throw an error when you try to access a `NULL` or `undefined` object.

Using the elvis operator `?.` atleasts removes the error you were having in the `html`

**UPDATE**

Fixed one of your functions :

```
  moveToTableTwo() {

      console.log(this.dataSource.data)
      this.selection.selected.forEach((k,item) => {

        this.dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(k),1); 
        this.checkedDataSource.data.push(k);
      });
      console.log(this.dataSource.data)
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
      this.checkedDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.checkedDataSource.data);

  }
```

Try the same with the other function.

**UPDATE**

Your other function should be like this :

```
moveToTableOne() {

  this.checkedSelection.selected.forEach((k,item) => {this.checkedDataSource.data.splice(this.checkedDataSource.data.indexOf(k),1);
        this.dataSource.data.push(k);
      });
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
      this.checkedDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.checkedDataSource.data);


} }
```

Comment: yes i tried that but its only removing the error but the problem still exists.

Comment: yes its transferring the selected rows and also splicing .... but when i select and transfer second row , the first row is again repeating in the second table.

Comment: I just did the first function for you , did you fix the second function which was used to transfer from 2nd Table to 1st based on the fix i gave ?

Comment: yes its also working and i have changed the function for transferring from 2 to 1.....

Comment: i tried to fix this issue but i am not getting y the previously moved row is again repeated while moving the second row